# A new data added in dynamodb ,the display of on tableau change accordingly

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, tableau-api

A new data added in dynamodb and the display on tableau change accordingly
Is it possible to do this?
Now I am connecting these two through redshift but it seems impossible.

Comment: This is a very vague question with few details. In general you can look into DynamoDB Streams and Lambda functions. Lambda functions can subscribe to changes in DynamoDB tables and then update data through the Tableau API.

Comment: Since DynamoDB actually cannot directly connect to tableau the way that I update to tableau is through redshift and would like to see whether there are other good choices.